# How to nailed faster performance of ubuntu desktop / server?

Tags: server, 22.04

I have MAC Mini with MAC OS and compare to that I have powerful Ubuntu desktop hardware.

Now expected that Ubuntu memory management should be much better and faster than MAC OS.

As well Skype and Chrome all most kills memories in Ubuntu compare to MAC OS.

I am in favor of Ubuntu, because of my 20+ desktop have Ubuntu.

My all desk have NVME SSD on board.

Please suggest or tips

Comment: NO, I recommend memory optimization like macos, preload eat lots of memory, where as mac do best with less memory.

Comment: I just tried, preload, yes it bit consume memory, but speedup my desktop ubuntu edition, but really its kills battery consumption, even battery saver mode is on. 

thanks, that's helps.

Might preload @ubuntu core team make default for desktop and avoid it in server edition, make sure preload respect laptop power management as well.

Comment: macOS is very clever about getting good performance without killing the battery.